# Происхождение слова "фифа"

Tags: этимология, жаргон

Неужели жаргонизм "фифа" происходит от междометия "фи"?

Answer (score 5):

Это не жаргон - сниженная лексика; помета: *пренебр.*

И таки да, исконное: [возникло на базе удвоения фи](https://etymological.academic.ru/5638/%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B0).

Смотрим **[ФИ](https://etymological.academic.ru/5605/%D1%84%D0%B8)**:

> Искон. Вербализация звукосочетания, передающего свист. Ср. освистать
>   (в знак неодобрения или презрения).
>
> ---

А "фи"-то и нерусское вовсе - с точки зрения другого словаря...

[Исторический словарь галлицизмов русского языка](https://gallicismes.academic.ru/40296/%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B0)

ФИФА ы, ж. fi! или fi-fi, сдвоенного fi! Пустая, легкомысленная женщина, девушка, думающая только о нарядах и развлечениях (неодобр.) БАС-1. *Кулачками ударяя по крышке рояля, она завопила: - Жене не привез, какой-нибудь фифке отдал, а я все магазины исходила, три часа в очереди стояла, чтоб только тебе сатину на блузу набрать.* Л. Савин Вещи. // Звезда 1930 9 39. *Аким нарадоваться не мог Элиной сноровке - этакая фифа, а иголка не валится из рук.*

И ещё много примеров по ссылке.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, я не думаю, что это так. Более убедительным мне кажется родство с прагерманским wifa, оно сохраняется в языках этой группы, например, в английском wife.

[Middle English wif, wyf, from Old English wif (neuter) "woman, female, lady," also, but not especially, "wife," from Proto-Germanic *wīfa- (source also of Old Saxon, Old Frisian wif, Old Norse vif, Danish and Swedish viv, Middle Dutch, Dutch wijf, Old High German wib, German Weib), of uncertain origin and disputed etymology, not found in Gothic.] Etymology.com

И ещё: В современном датском есть слово wijf. Сейчас это просто сленговое слов, означающее девушку. Однако прежде оно было близко по значению английскому bitch.